# Return queryable table from a stored procedure/function in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server

I'm struggling to understand some of the other questions on SO about this.

I basically have a stored procedure that does a little logic, followed by a `SELECT` with a load of inner joins.

I want to able to call this to return my results, but then run a query against it.

I've seen something in another question about Table Valued Functions but I can't quite grasp how they work. Can anyone help me out?

Comment: What does it mean "does a little logic"?, if your sp need to insert or update data (and some other operations) and then do the `SELECT`, then this won't be able to work on a function

Comment: it examines the passed in value and if it's an integer it runs a slightly different SELECT

Comment: But does this slightly different `SELECT` have the same columns than the other one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an example of the function you can implement:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[YourFunction](@PassedValue VARCHAR(50))  
RETURNS @RtnValue TABLE 
(
    Col1 INT,
    Col2 INT
) 
AS  
BEGIN 
    IF @PassedValue NOT LIKE '%[^0-9]%'
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO @RtnValue
        SELECT 1,1 -- Your first query here
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO @RtnValue
        SELECT 2,2 -- Your second query here
    END

    RETURN
END
```

Then you can use it as a table on your query:

```
SELECT *
FROM dbo.YourFunction('123')
```

Answer (score 1):

[Here](http://www.sommarskog.se/share_data.html#UDF) is straightforward, simple example of creation and use of a table-valued function.

Depending on your requirements and SQL Server version (2008+ required), you may want to look at creating a stored procedure with a [table-valued parameter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510489.aspx) if you need to do complex processing on the result set. This involves creating a [user-defined table type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb522526.aspx) and declaring an input parameter of this type in the stored procedure to process results.